# Filtering an array of JSON

Tags: angularjs, angular

Hey I am following another guide and really struggling to get it working for me. Somewhat new to Angular so I am sure this is a simple issue. Can anyone help me?

The front end shows all the JSON objects at the page load but when I type anything they all disappear.

```
 _ninjaFilter:string
 get ninjaFilter():string{
   return this._ninjaFilter;
 }
 set ninjaFilter(value:string){
   this._ninjaFilter = value
   console.log(this.filteredNinjas, this.ninjaFilter)
   this.filteredNinjas = this.ninjaFilter ? this.performFilter(this.ninjaFilter) : this.ninjas
 }

 performFilter(filterBy: string): any{
  filterBy = filterBy.toLocaleLowerCase();
  console.log(filterBy)
  return this.ninjas.filter(ninja=>{
      ninja.name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(filterBy)
      //tried a if statement here to console log match and it does log out match
    //also have tried .indexOf(filterby) !== -1

    })
 }
  filteredNinjas: any

    ninjas=[{
    'name':'yoshi',
    'belt':'red'
  },
  {
    'name':'luigi',
    'belt':'black'
  },
  {
    'name':'Ryu',
    'belt':'green'
  }]


  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { 
    this.filteredNinjas = this.ninjas //create new array to filter on
    this.ninjaFilter='' //set initial filter string to null
  }
```

and the view:

```
<h2>Ninja Listing</h2>
<input type='text' id="filter"
[(ngModel)]='ninjaFilter' />
<ul id="ninja-listing">
    <li *ngFor="let ninja of filteredNinjas">
        <div class='single-ninja'>
            <span [ngStyle]="{background: ninja.belt}">{{ninja.belt}} belt</span>
            <h3>{{ninja.name}}</h3>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is console log (first page load and then me typing)

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}] "r"
directory.component.ts:23 r
directory.component.ts:17 [] "ry"
directory.component.ts:23 ry
directory.component.ts:17 [] "ryu"
directory.component.ts:23 ryu
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't return anything inside your filter function. You should return a condition there:

```
return this.ninjas.filter(ninja => {
      return ninja.name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(filterBy);
});
```